# How to prevent Firefox from closing when app tabs are open?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, about-config

Is there any way, via `about:config` or otherwise, to prevent Firefox from closing when [app tabs](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-are-app-tabs) are open?

I'm using Firefox 5.0.1 and 8.0a1 nightly.

Comment: I am really not sure what you mean. Please clarify.

Comment: @user606723 - I am exactly sure what Jags means. http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-are-app-tabs

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about app tabs. Anyway, this functionality works for me by default. I should add that upgraded from firefox 3, and still have the firefox 3 look and feel and whatever firefox 3's defaults are.

Comment: It is a common problem, and I couldn't find any solution to this problem other than manually locking the app tabs or restoring app tabs sessions, but I suggest you take a look at [this](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/765031#answer-166925). I don't know why this bug is not being fixed, and why none of the tabs addons have an auto-lock app tabs option, but I am sure it's only a matter of time until it will be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

`Browser.tabs.closeWindowWithLastTab` set to `false` does it for me.

Comment: @ user606723 & Shinrai many thanks. What I meant, when I have 2 or more app-tabs open & if I accidentally close (red X at top right corner) Firefox, Firefox won't even display a warning that it usually displays when I have 2 or more *regular* tabs open and if I tries to close Firefox. What I would prefer (my personal 1st choice option) is that Firefox throw an error that first you need to close app-tab manually (right click on app-tab and click close) then you can close Firefox. My 2nd choice would be FF throw a warning that it displays while closing 2 or more regular tabs. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [long standing issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=419009) with Firefox. One possible workaround is to use the [Always Ask extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/always-ask/).

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but the best I've found.  Thanks.